# Kurento Media Server crashes on start when using certs

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, kurento

I'm using kurento media server 6.6.1 on a Ubuntu 10.4 box in AWS. It runs fine normally, and I'm attempting to use wss, so I uncomment the security lines in /etc/kurento/kurento.conf.json so the file looks like:

```
{
 "mediaServer" : {
  "resources": {
   //  //Resources usage limit for raising an exception when an object creation is attempted
   //  "exceptionLimit": "0.8",
   //  // Resources usage limit for restarting the server when no objects are alive
   //  "killLimit": "0.7",
   // Garbage collector period in seconds
   "garbageCollectorPeriod": 240
  },
  "net" : {
   "websocket": {
   "port": 8888,
   "secure": {
    "port": 8433,
    "certificate": "/etc/letsencrypt/archive/<MYDOMAIN>/fullchain1.pem",
    "password": ""
   },
   //"registrar": {
   //  "address": "ws://localhost:9090",
   //  "localAddress": "localhost"
   //},
    "path": "kurento",
    "threads": 10
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I've also verified that my certs are in the correct location and are valid.

When I restart the service, I get the following output in my /var/log/kurento-media-server/media-server_error.log file, and the service doesn't start (or give any other logs).

```
kurento-media-server: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:648: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (thread 140077491206272, pid 7622)
Stack trace:
[gsignal]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:0x35428
[abort]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:0x3702A
[uselocale]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:0x2DBD7
[__assert_fail]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:0x2DC82
0x4CC67A at /usr/bin/kurento-media-server
[kurento::kms_init_logging(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int)]
/usr/bin/kurento-media-server:0x4EF234
[gst_debug_log_valist]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0:0x62EE6
[gst_debug_log]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0:0x6303B
[kurento::MediaSet::~MediaSet()]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6:0xA809B
[std::_Sp_counted_ptr<kurento::MediaSet*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose()]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6:0xB06D2
[std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release()]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6:0xA3916
[__cxa_finalize]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:0x3A36A
0xA2B53 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscoreimpl.so.6
```